# What do the terms used in OpenPGP keyserver SKS mean? (sig, sbind, sig3, exp2, Policy, ...)

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, pgp, gnupg

When viewing a key record in a public key server, [such as this one](https://sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=0x0B7F8B60E3EDFAE3), there are lots of keywords used: sig, sig3, exp3, Policy, sbind…). I understand that "sig" probably means a signature, but what's the difference between a "sig" and a "sig3" and a "sbind"? And what exactly is a "Policy" record?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In OpenPGP, signatures are used not only for documents, but also for **certifications between primary keys with different levels of trust** (`sig`, `sig1`, `sig2`, `sig3`; as hex codes `0x10`-`0x13` in this order) and several more internal stuff.

Signatures are also very important for **binding subkeys to primary keys (and the other way round)**: these are displayed as `sbind` signatures by key servers, and a simple `sig` by GnuPG, and have signature types `0x18` and `0x19` in OpenPGP. User IDs are bound by "normal" certification signatures, also called self-signatures or selfsigs.

If for any reason you want to undo a signature, this is generally not possible (you cannot delete anything from the key server network). Instead, you again issue another kind of signature, a **revocation** of a key (`0x20`), revocation of a subkey (`0x28`) or revocation of a certificate (`0x30`). All of those will be displayed as `revok` by most key servers, and `rev` by GnuPG.

A **certification policy** displayed with the key word `Policy` drops out of this list, a little bit, as it does not denote another signature type, but is a *signature subpacket* describing a so-called certification policy. I already left a more detailed description in ["What are you saying when you sign a PGP key?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/67639/19837). **Notations** also describe a certification, and could for example be used to describe how the signer identified the signee.

The signature types are defined in [RFC 4880, OpenPGP, 5.2.1.  Signature Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.1), signature subpackets only a little bit further down in the same document.

Comment: Jens, thanks a lot for the super detailed answer. I understand now that signatures (**sig***) are used for issuing certificates. One thing I still don't get is, why would one issue a certificate (`0x30`) in order to undo a signature?

Comment: Technically, all of those are signatures; I (and others) prefer using the term _certification_ for signatures on keys. If you want to revoke a certification (thus, a signature on somebody else's key), you issue a new revocation (revocation signature), which tells "The previously issued certification is invalid". I think you misinterpreted my wording, which I slightly adjusted to hopefully remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good write up about [PGP at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy).

According to the [GPG manual (pgp for linux)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg) under `--check-sigs` flag:

> The status of the verification is indicated by a flag directly
>   following  the  "sig"  tag...

So, looking at that:

- `Sig3` means that another user has personally checked the fingerprint
  or key.
- If it says `Sig` only the means another user hasn't personally
  checked [the] fingerprint or key. (They're not vouched for.)

**Other records**

`sbind` is the time where the username was bound to the key. Basically when the record was created. This may be impacted by a policy.

`revok` is where the binding was revoked, so the key is no longer valid.

`Policy` is a specific user's policy in regard to how they'll exchange communications, their terms for contact, (and how they won't).

Comment: Also thanks for for answering :) I understand almost everything now.