# Is it practical and/or secure to get my friends to remotely sign my OpenPGP public key?

Tags: pgp, openpgp

My best friends would trust who I am and I would also trust who they are, without looking at our government-issued IDs. We went to the same schools and same classes for many years.

However, they now live on the other side of the planet.

Is it practical and/or secure to get them to sign my public key, via something like a live video chat where I read my public key out-loud to them?

Would this have been good enough before [recent advances in audio and video synthesis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Yq67CjDqvw)?

Are there still other ways to prove my identity remotely, without resorting to shared secrets from the past when we still lived in the same city?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no definition on how you have to verify identities for OpenPGP certifications. This is completely up to you -- some people define a [certification policy](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/67578/19837) because of this.

Whether to accept a video chat or not depends on the policy of the certifying side. I would still not expect an attacker being able to render photorealistic video footage in real-time; so embed the key exchange in a conversation, or include multiple persons and for example hand-writing the fingerprint while reading to a whiteboard. Additionally, the paper referenced used many hours of high quality video footage for training -- would you expect this to be available at all? Finally, is an attacker with such powerful computing resources and capabilities available that would risk being observed in such an attack?